# Laravel upgrade 5 to 10 after update getDoctrineColumn getType query takes too long to execute

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, doctrine

Laravel upgrade 5 to 10 after update getDoctrineColumn getType query takes too long to execute

```
DB::connection()
->getDoctrineColumn(self::getTableName(), $col)
->getType()
->getName()
```

above query executes within second in laravel 5.8 version but after update to 10 it executes around 5-6 seconds how to reduce or is there anything i am missing ?

execution time needs to reduce in above query

Comment: cache, select just the collumns you want, use index etc..

Answer (score 0):

Migrating directly from Laravel 5 to 10 is a big leap. It's advisable to switch first to a version with a small gap, such as 8, to see how it behaves before migrating completely to 10.